# how to stay on same page after upload file and click on submit in jquerymobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I was upload a file after click on submit button the page will navigate to 
     .php file and get success messsage. But i want to stay on same page after
     click on submit button with out using ajax.
     Please help me.
     Thanks.

```
  HTML code:

  <div id="videos" class="uploadVideos" >
  <form name="uploadForm" action=".../videoApp/services/upload.php"   
  id="uploadForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="POST" data-transition="pop"
  data-direction="reverse" data-ajax="false" data-push-state="false" target="_self"  
  enctype="multipart/form-data" >

    <input type="hidden" name="familyID"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="name" />

     <label for="file"><b>Add Videos: </b></label>
     <input type="file" name="file" id="file" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="videoUpload" data-icon="check" data-role="button"  
      data-theme="e" />
      </form>
     </div>
```

Comment: without Ajax not possible. Once upload is done on php page, `window.history.back()` to navigate back.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have to use an AJAX call as it is the only way to post a form dynamically without a page reload. In the `onsubmit` you can call a function like `post_form();` containing a code like this:

```
function post_form(e){   
    var formData = new FormData($('#uploadForm')[0]);   
    $.ajax({  
        url: ".../videoApp/services/upload.php",  
        type: 'POST',   
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {  
            alert(data); 
        }  
    });  
}
```

Comment: Another way is I have added data-ajax="false attribute to the form and it does properly upload the file. But then because it is a form submit it opens up a new page with the action url. What I want is to handle the response of form submit and show an appropriate screen.
But since ajax is disabled, not sure how to handle the response, because don't see a way to specify callback for submit. help me